# Unable to execute multiple MailApp.sendEmail() in doGet()

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to automate the sending of emails via Google Apps Script and Google Forms. Basically, on form submit, it sends an email to the desired email address, with the fields indicated on the Google Form. After which, I have a doGet() function that looks like the following:

```
function doGet(e) {

    // Sends email to Person 1
    MailApp.sendEmail('test@example.com', "Email 1", 'Test');

    // Sends email to Person 2
    MailApp.sendEmail('test@example.com', "Email 2", 'Test2');

}
```

However, I noticed that only the first email gets triggered, while the 2nd sendEmail function is not being triggered. The Execution Transcript Logs is also not showing any errors. However, if I debug it on Google Apps Script directly and run my doGet() function, the 2 emails get sent as expected.

Not sure why this is the case, would appreciate if anyone can enlighten me on this!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, how about redeploying Web Apps as new version and tryin it again? From your question, I couldn't confirm whether you had already done it. When the script of Web Apps was modified, it is required to redeploy as new version for reflecting the latest script. If this was not the solution, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for reminding me this! Not sure why it wouldn't work without redeploying my app as a new version, but that seem to be the problem. You're spot on!

Comment: @Tanaike Sure, I've posted it as an answer for sharing with others.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tanaike rightfully pointed out, the solution is to re-deploy the apps script as a new Web App in order to view the latest, updated changes.